# Help Converting a Onclick JavaScript button in a Managed Package to a Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

CODE:

```
 {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/26.0/connection.js")}
 {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/26.0/apex.js")}
   var ABN = "{!Account.ABN__ABN__c}";
   if (ABN != "") {
  navigateToUrl("/apex/ABN__validateABN?Id={!Account.Id}");
   }
   else 
   {
    alert("A valid ABN was not found");
  }
```

Managed package - ABN Validation

Comment: What have you done so far? You cannot expect us to write the Code. All you have to do is create a Lightning Component and put a redirection to "ABN__validateABN" page.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a lightning component with "force:lightningQuickAction" this interface. And go to object -> button,link and action -> new action-> select action type as lightning component and save it. Go to page layout and add quick action in SF1 and mobile experience section.